# override existing onkeydown embedded in html element

Tags: javascript, overriding, onkeydown

In html element onkeydown function is called.:

"<"input title="Enter Value" onkeydown="return RadWindowprompt_detectenter('{0}', event, this);" type="text"  class="rwDialogInput" value="{2}" "/>"

But I need to override it with my document.onkeydown function

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', captureEnter, true);

    function captureEnter(evt) {

        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (evt) {
            ele_type = evt.srcElement.getAttribute("id");
            if (!(ele_type == $("[id$='AddNewLink']") || ele_type == $("[id$='Add_New']") || ele_type == $("[id$='AddNewImage']"))) {
                ele_type = null;
                return;
            }

        }

    };
```

How do I cause my function to run instead of executing the html embedded onkeydown?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can stop the propagation of the event, if you don't want the `onkeydown` handler to execute

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', captureEnter, true);

function captureEnter(evt) {
  snippet.log('captureEnter')
  evt.stopPropagation()
};

function RadWindowprompt_detectenter() {
  snippet.log('RadWindowprompt_detectenter')
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<input title="Enter Value" onkeydown="return RadWindowprompt_detectenter('{0}', event, this);" type="text" class="rwDialogInput" value="{2}"/>
```

---

Another way could be is to remove the `onkeydown` handler like

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', captureEnter, true);

function captureEnter(evt) {
  snippet.log('captureEnter')
};


var els = document.querySelectorAll('input.rwDialogInput[onkeydown]');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].removeAttribute('onkeydown');
}

function RadWindowprompt_detectenter() {
  snippet.log('RadWindowprompt_detectenter')
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<input title="Enter Value" onkeydown="return RadWindowprompt_detectenter('{0}', event, this);" type="text" class="rwDialogInput" value="{2}" />
```

Comment: The problem with above code: 1. evt.stopPropagation() never gets executed   because the first time it calls :   onkeydown="return RadWindowprompt_detectenter('{0}', event, this);" since its embedded.                 2. remove attribute doesn work because no point of removing the attribute if onkeydown is already called!                                                                   The problem is RadWindowprompt_detectenter is called from 3rd party dll (RadContol) hence I cannot made changes/remove onkeydown  embedded in element

Comment: @user1463110 did you try any of these solutions? - The attribute is remove on page load...

Comment: evt.stopPropagation() is the important part here